# AngularJS - possibilities for input directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have question about directives. I have directive:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.directive('hello', function() {
  return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      replace: 'true',
      template: '<h3>Hello World!!</h3>'
  };
});
```

I tried put this directive to page more way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en" ng-app="myapp">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My HTML File</title>
  <script src="../js/angular-1.4.7.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/directives/directives.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<hello/>
<div data-hello ></div>
<div data-hello ></div>
<hello/>


</body>
</html>
```

I was expecting 4x Hello world!! on page but there is only 1x. When I remove first input (`<hello/>`) so there is all ok is there 3x. Why are rules for combination input of directives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well nothing there seems to be wrong, but based on your description there is one thing you can try. You may find the browser is interpreting your custom HTML tags "incorrectly" and not recognising that they're being closed. If this is the case, then you will only see one, because the other ones are being contained inside the first `div` and therefore being replaced. Try changing your markup to the following instead:

```
<hello></hello>
<div data-hello></div>
<div data-hello></div>
<hello></hello>
```

See if that works

Comment: Thanks. I use Chrome actually.